# I have now updated/graded to 22.04 - prefer LTS versions. Lost with some settings

Tags: system-installation, updates, 22.04

I guess it was inevitable that I would have to upgrade/update.
(From 21.04 to 22.04)

Ok, I am stuck with a couple of things that have hit me/been changed and as much as I can't really change them, I would like help understanding them.

On the older version - and earlier - if I press the "super" button I get a view of all open windows.  Handy, especially when you have as many open as I do.
(Mostly Firefox)
Before I would/could see a small icon of their screen.
Now I have the firefox icon embossed/overlayed on top of the icon.
Makes it difficult to see which is which.

Could someone please help me - with these questions?

Pictures to show the difference.

[image: How the screen was in 21.04]
[image: the new screen]

Comment: It would help if you said what have upgraded from. Please edit the question and add this info.

Comment: Two things stand out: #1 There is not and never has been a supported upgrade path directly from 21.04 to 22.04 and even the interim releases have long passed the support window. #2 It's clear that you've made heavy customizations to your desktop beyond the scope of "stock" customization settings. Issues are more likely when the upgrade wasn't tested and wasn't supported. You'll likely need to set all of this back up however you did it in the past. Unfortunately you'll also need to ask about individual issues separately. We do not allow multiple questions to be joined together.

Comment: The main problem is the icons on top of the windows as shown by the screen shots.
In regard to customising:  The only thing I think I had was the background screen image and "theme" set to dark.  Oh, I also had X11 not WAYLAND.

Comment: Maybe you don't remember making changes but we can tell by the details in the screenshot that is not true... Enough said, the current question is too broad. You'll need to problem solve each issue independently. If you need help, you'll need to ask about each issue on its own. Feel free to ask multiple questions if you need to, but do not combine multiple issues in one question.